# How can I programmatically find these duplicate records?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, duplicates

I've got a few instances where some duplicate records were created and now I need to clean them out since I've figured out what was causing them.

I have `ResponseSets` and each ResponseSet `has_many Responses`.

Each `Response` has a value for `answer_id` and that `answer_id` should only be present once for any `ResponseSet`.

So what I need to do is find duplicate `Responses` for each `ResponseSet` based on if there are more than one of the same `answer_id`.

My brain hurts trying to explain, so if more details are needed, please just ask.

Comment: Sounds like something you could accomplish through SQL alone if it's a one time deal.  We need to see your table schema for the `Response` and `ResponseSet` tables to be able to accurately help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ResponseSets.all.each do |set|
  answer_ids = []
  set.responses.each do |r|
    puts "Response #{r.id}: set=#{set.id}, answer=#{r.answer_id}"
    if answer_ids.include? r.answer_id
      puts "Duplicate found!"
      # r.destroy  # Uncomment when you feel it is safe
    else
      answer_ids << r.answer_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: David, can you think of a way to speed this up? here's what I'm ultimately doing to run this (and I'm running via a rake task on Heroku), and it's taking hours to run. https://gist.github.com/4cdc8459626437c72126

Comment: Well how many rows do you have in each table?  One way to speed it up might be to fetch ALL of the responses in a giant query at the beginning, so you just have one select query instead of N.  But if you have a huge database then that might be a huge drain on your computer's memory.  Maybe you should run it with ruby-prof and figure out which part is the slowest.  My answer was not designed for speed because you didn't say anything about how much data you had.

Answer (score 3):

This should give you ID's of objects with duplicates.

```
select rs.id, r.answer_id, count(r.id)
from response_sets rs
join responses r on r.response_set_id = rs.id
group by rs.id, r.answer_id
having count(r.id) > 1;
```

This query returns a table of ResponseSets' IDs (rs.id) for which the number of Responses with an answer r.answer_id is equal to count(r.id). We're interested only in duplicates, so we take onl those which have `count(r.id) > 1`.

Now, let's get actual Response's IDs by wrapping the query above in another `select`.

```
select r.id
from responses r
join (
  select rs.id as rs_id, r.answer_id as a_id, r.id as r_id
  from response_sets rs
  join responses r on r.response_set_id = rs.id
  group by rs.id, r.answer_id
  having count(r.id) > 1
) on r.response_set_id = rs_id
where r.answer_id = a_id and r.id != r_id;
```

What do we have here? We take what we've obtained from the previous query and ask for IDs of Responses whose `answer_id` is equal to the answer ID with known duplicates within a given ResponseSet. Since it will return *all* responses with a given `answer_id` within a ResponseSet, we might want to select only duplicates by adding `and r.id != r_id`. Delete this predicate and see how it changes the returned set.

It's pure SQL so it should be way faster than multiple queries through an ORM. You might consider adding an index on the foreign key `response_set_id`, but it's hard to tell for sure without benchmarking on real data or seeing a query execution plan.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, but this just didn't seem accurate. I'd find responses that were definitely duplicates and those id's wouldn't show up in this query. I like the _idea_ of a simple SQL query to grab all the duplicates, but in practice something didn't work out. :(

Comment: @Shpigford, I see. I should have clarified that this query returns a table of ResponseSets' IDs (`rs.id`) for which there are `count(r.id)` Responses with an answer `r.answer_id`. It will return rows for which `count(r.id) > 1`, that is breaking the uniqueness. In practice you'd have to either wrap it in another query or -- since the majority of the work has been already done -- use the ORM to find appropriate responses. It would be something like `ResponseSet.find(rs.id).responses.find_by_answer_id r.answer_id`, with `rs.id` and `r.answer_id` replaced with values obtained using the query.

Comment: @Shpigford, on a second thought, I've updated the answer. Now it should give you a table of ID's of Responses to delete. Feel free to add a comment if some extra clarification is needed.